# updateApp widget not working for remoteView

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and created a custom notification with collapsed and expanded view. I want to update Image of ImageView in expanded view. The expanded view layout file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="256dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/light_salnmon"
    android:text="This is expanded notification"
    android:id="@+id/text_view_expanded"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    />
<TextView
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Testing is awecome"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to update image in imageview with following line of code, but it does not work

```
                final RemoteViews expanded_view=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_expanded);
                Bitmap largeIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), sampleImages[finalI]);
                expanded_view.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, largeIcon2);
                
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(counter,expanded_view);
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(counter,R.id.image);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Expanded view image updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here **counter** is notification Id not App widget Id. I do not know how to get App Widget Id for a notification.
please help me resolve this issue. Please Ignore any mistake not related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

please follow this code

```java
// Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
RemoteViews notificationExpandableLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_large);

// Apply the layouts to the notification
Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationExpandableLayout)
        .build();
```